# Raster Calculator or Local-Combine tool? (in ArcPy)

Tags: arcpy, raster, field-calculator

i have 3 classified rasters and i wanted to use the following query from r. calculator:

```
(rclslope>=45) & (rclmosaic>=2000) & (rclfocal>15)
```

to arcpy. How can i write it?
Is it better to use local - combine tool with arcpy to do it?

I am using ArcGis 10.2

Answer (score 4):

with arcpy

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

out = (Raster("rclslope")>=45) & (Raster("rclmosaic")>=2000) & (Raster("rclfocal")>15)
out.save("output_path")
```

Comment: thank you very much, i had a problemwith spaces and i solved it